# Why is Jquery returning the wrong length?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to add an element to a form. Then I count the total number of elements with that class. However, Jquery .length returns the number of elements times two.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(function () {
    function updateWeight() {
        var z = $("input.count").length;
        alert(z);
    }
    $("#addCatalogItem").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("inventory_auto_complete.php", {
                term: request.term,
                supplier_id: $('#supplier_id').val()
            }, response);
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var q = ui.item.product_id;
            $('#product_id').val(q);
            var r = ui.item.value;
            $('#product').val(r);
            var field = '<label>' + r + '</label><input class=\"count\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" name=\"field[' + q + ']\"/>';
            var $item = $("form");
            $(field).appendTo($item);
            updateWeight();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="supplier_id" value="1"/>
    <input id="addCatalogItem"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at your dynamically created HTML?

Comment: @matt: I would say use Firebug to inspect generated html will be very helpful.

Comment: Don't blame `length` or `jQuery`. The problem is in your code. And if you could put HTML, that would also help us figure out the problem. Question: how many `alert(z)` did you get?

Comment: Yep, checked it out. Only one field is created each time. But its being counted twice.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the HTML. alert(z) is twice the amount of actual elements.

Comment: how many times does alert happens in a single run?

Comment: Simple test case, works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WJJws/

Comment: That works! Although there's no other form on my page. A unique ID solves the problem. Also thanks for the link to JSfiddle, that's going to come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var $item = $("form");` would take all the form in the page. Maybe you got some other form somewhere in the page.

[simple test case](http://jsfiddle.net/WJJws/) of [Yi Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313758/yi-jiang) shows that your code should work perfectly.

[Here's a test case](http://jsfiddle.net/WJJws/2/) that demonstrate same result as your problem.

My suggestion is you give the form an id then use it as the selector, `var $item = $("#formID");` .